# Cannot launch UWP executable outside of Visual Studio

Tags: c#, windows, uwp, visual-studio-2017, exe

**Problem:** The `.exe` files that I found (MyProject\bin\x86\Release and MyProject\obj\x86\Release) do nothing when I attempt to launch them. Do I have the wrong .exe location, or am I missing a step?

**Purpose:** I am attempting to create a desktop shortcut to launch the program.

**Related info:**

- This is a C# UWP Visual Studio 2017 project
- The app launches correctly from the Visual Studio IDE.
- The app launches correctly from the Windows Start Menu icon that Visual Studio apparently created. (Where is THAT linked to?)
- (Searching online only yielded results relevant to launching Visual Studio itself, which is why I am asking here.)

Comment: Can you please right click on your app in Windows Start menu icon and see where it’s pointing to in the properties.

Comment: @bestinamir 'Properties' is not one of the options that appear in the right-click menu. The App Settings also does not reveal any paths.

Comment: Ok, drag it (this app) from start menu to your desktop instead, Windows should create shortcut for you.

Comment: @bestinamir Huh, I did not think of that! Thank you, that worked!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[You can't run Universal Windows Platform (UWP) executables directly.](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/148375/uwp-executable-file-does-not-run.html) You need to [make an APPX-formatted package](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/packaging-uwp-apps) and install it, then the app will be available on your Start Menu.